# What are the standard ownership settings for files in the `.gnupg` folder?

Tags: permissions, gpg, ownership

What are the standard ownership settings for files in the `.gnupg` folder?

After doing `sudo chown u:u *` mine now looks like this:

```
drwx------ 2 u u 4,0K jan 18 22:53 crls.d
drwx------ 2 u u 4,0K jan 18 22:33 openpgp-revocs.d
drwx------ 2 u u 4,0K jan 18 22:33 private-keys-v1.d
-rw------- 1 u u    0 sep 28 02:12 pubring.gpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 u u 2,4K jan 18 22:33 pubring.kbx
-rw------- 1 u u   32 jan 18 22:28 pubring.kbx~
-rw------- 1 u u  600 jan 19 22:15 random_seed
-rw------- 1 u u    0 sep 28 02:13 secring.gpg
srwxrwxr-x 1 u u    0 jan 20 10:20 S.gpg-agent
-rw------- 1 u u 1,3K jan 18 23:47 trustdb.gpg
```

However, before that, originally at least `pubring.gpg`,`secring.gpg` and `random_seed` were owned by root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.gnupg` directory and its contents should be owned by the user whose keys are stored therein and who will be using them. There is in principle no problem with a root-owned `.gnupg` directory in your home directory, *if root is the only user that you use GnuPG as* (in that case one could argue that the directory should live in `/root` or that you should do things differently).

I can see nothing wrong with the file permissions in the file listing that you have posted. The `.gnupg` folder itself should additionally be inaccessible by anyone other than the owner and user of the keys.

---

The reason why the files may initially have been owned by root could be because GnuPG was initially run as root or by a process executing as root (maybe some package manager software or similar).

---

GnuPG does permission checks and will warn you if any of the files have unsafe permissions.  These warnings may be turned off (don't do that):

> `--no-permission-warning`
>
> Suppress the warning about unsafe file and home directory
>                 (`--homedir`) permissions. Note that the permission checks that
>                 GnuPG performs are not intended to be authoritative, but rather
>                 they simply warn about certain common permission problems. Do
>                 not assume that the lack of a warning means that your system is
>                 secure.
>
> Note that the warning for unsafe `--homedir` permissions cannot be
>                 suppressed in the `gpg.conf` file, as this would allow an attacker
>                 to place an unsafe `gpg.conf` file in place, and use this file to
>                 suppress warnings about itself. The `--homedir` permissions
>                 warning may only be suppressed on the command line.

The `--homedir` directory referred to above is the `.gnupg` directory, usually at `$HOME/.gnupg` unless changed by using `--homedir` or setting `GNUPGHOME`.

Additionally, the file storing the secret keys will be changed to read/write only by default by GnuPG, unless this behaviour is turned off (don't do that either):

> `--preserve-permissions`
>
> Don't change the permissions of a secret keyring back to user
>                 read/write only. Use this option only if you really know what
>                 you are doing.

This applies to GnuPG 2.2.3, and the excerpts above are from the `gpg2` manual on an OpenBSD system.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why the files have been owned by `root`. As you can see below, these files should be owned solely by the user.

These are standard ownership information of `~/.gnupg` folder under **Debian**:

```
drwx------ 2 vlastimil vlastimil 4.0K Mar 24  2017 crls.d
drwx------ 2 vlastimil vlastimil 4.0K Dec  4  2016 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  54K Nov  4 10:43 pubring.kbx
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  52K Jun  8  2017 pubring.kbx~
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  600 Jun 21  2017 random_seed
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 1.5K Nov  4 10:44 trustdb.gpg
```

These are standard ownership information of `~/.gnupg` folder under **Mint**:

```
drwx------ 2 vlastimil vlastimil 4.0K Jan 17 07:05 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil   50 Jul 13  2016 gpg-agent-info-vb-nb-mint
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 9.2K Nov 21  2015 gpg.conf
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 3.5M Jan 21 15:18 pubring.gpg
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 3.5M Jan 17 07:06 pubring.gpg~
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  600 Jan 21 15:20 random_seed
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  20K Jan 21 15:18 secring.gpg
srwxrwxr-x 1 vlastimil vlastimil    0 Jan 21 08:49 S.gpg-agent
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 2.6K Jan 17 07:06 trustdb.gpg
```